# Add-On one time configuration parameters

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on writing a script to synch email from gmail to another system.  One item the script will need is configuration parameters from the user to the other system ( username / password ).

The configuration should only need to be done once for the user and then the script will be set up to run at regular intervals ( probably hourly ).

How can I prompt the user for username & password when they install the add-on and store it so the script can use those values?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the docs for user properties service. Store it there its per user.
Note that add-ons dont yet allow time triggers so you cant yet do the 'regular intervals' part with add-ons.